# jQuery UI sortable usability problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a nice card stack in which I want the cards to be sortable. To stack the cards they have a negative bottom margin which messes up the sorting.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLfumdwb/1/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>

<style>
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  li {
    width: 347px;
    height: 226px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 3px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin-bottom: -120px;
    border: solid 1px #F00;
    background-color: #FFF;
    transform: skewX(-2deg);
   }
   li:not(:last-child) {
     margin-bottom: -191px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $("ul").sortable({});
  });
</script>
```

I have been trying for hours but were not able to resolve the problem. Does anyone have an idea, maybe for stacking the cards differently or using a sortable event to fix the behaviour?

Thank you very much

Comment: What behaviour are you talking about? The flickering?

Comment: @Yass Yes, the flickering and I find it very hard to correctly place the card where I want it to be. I tested in the newest Chrome, Firefox and Edge

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I got it: https://jsfiddle.net/vLfumdwb/4/

```
li {
  width: 347px;
  height: 35px;
}
li div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 226px;
  ...
}
```

I couldn't change anything with javascript but drawing the cards differently did the trick (card is only 35px in height now with a 226px height inner div instead of card with 226px height and a -191px negative bottom margin).